# fenv.h from C99 in C++11

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Does fenv.h from C99 exists in C++11? Is there any other ways to use function like fesetround? Maybe boost?

gcc 4.7.2 compiles this code:

```
#include <cfenv>

int main() {}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/ffbd8e8a24633c7e74f7bcead3b1a287

Answer (score 4):

> **Does `fenv.h` from `C99` exists in `C++11`?**

Yes it does.

**Reference:**

```
26.3 The floating-point environment [cfenv]
Standard C++11 26.3.1 Header <cfenv> synopsis [cfenv.syn]
```

---

> **Is there any other ways to use function like `fesetround()`? Maybe boost?**

The function `fesetround()` is already provided by `cfenv` in C++11.
Also, `fenv.h` also exists in C++11 so as to provide backward compatability to c standard headers. It is covered under:

```
D.5 C standard library headers [depr.c.headers]
```

---

> **What is the difference between using `fenv.h` or `cfenv`?**

Including `cfenv` imports the symbol names in `std` namespace and *possibly* in Global namespace.
Including `fenv.h` imports the symbol names in Global namespace and *possibly* in `std` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

[Yes, it does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround). `cfenv` appears to be the correct header, and it was just added in C++11.